# how to drag map to four main directions in ionic 2?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, ionic2

In app which is using `google map js v3` I want to make a function that when tapping around the maker then map was opposite of dragging to that direction, for example 10 meters dragging to left when tapping to right.

Answer (score 0):

in my case by adding value to the `lat` `lng`  and `map.setCenter()` method moving map under marker